# expo version 2.4.2 version app not working / running in iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, expo, exp

followed links

```
https://github.com/expo/exp#viewing-a-project-on-your-phone
https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/VERSIONS.md
```

Installed latest expo version in iPhone 2.4.2 version app. They dropped QR Code scanner. facing issue in iPhone not able to run the react native app

```
1. exp login
2. exp start
3. exp send
4. given mobile number with country code (+91)
```

"expo send" sending one link to mobile. Though the iPhone and Mac both are connected to same network. I'm not able to open the app.

Getting

[image: this error]

Answer (score 2):

In terminal, Updated "exp" version with latest : 51.4.0

```
 "sudo npm i -g exp"
```

and then

```
1. exp login
2. exp start
3. exp send -s <phone number with country code(+91) or mail>
4. In mobile, open the link that received through mail or mobile number
```

Not sure for the first attempt expo app crashed but successfully opened for the 2nd time.

[image: reference]

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did and it works

1. Update your react-native-scripts to 1.12.0
2. Open the project from Expo XDE and send app link to your email or
   phone
3. Open the app from the link that was sent from Expo